# H.264 payload with no '0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x65'

Tags: h.264, transport-stream

I'm trying to detect I-frames in TS by searching for the:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x65
```

But, it doesn't work on some streams. In some streams this sequence occurs very rare. Is there any other way of detecting I-frames?

Edit:
I also tried saving TS to a file and then extracting H.264 payload. The extracted payload contains only a few 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x65 byte sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do looks like a blind guess. H.264 specification is [freely available](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264). `00 00 00 01` is described in Annex B "Byte stream format" section. Then your `65` is what maps to section 7.3.1 "NAL unit syntax":

[image]

So you can split your byte stream into NAL units correctly and identify why your heuristic is not detecting I-Frames. Specifically, you are assuming two bit value to be equal to three exactly.

Also, slice types are defined as this:

[image]

See also:

- [Possible Locations for Sequence/Picture Parameter Set(s) for H.264 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream)
- [How to detect I/P/B frame from H264 RTP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558271/how-to-detect-i-p-b-frame-from-h264-rtp-packet/26566708#26566708)

Comment: Okay, I should have looked for 0x25 and 0x45 as well. I tried, but these units are not present at all. Still, these standard fragments are not the answer to my question.

Comment: NAL type 5 will get you IDRs. To locate I frames which are not IDR, you will have to unwind bitstream for slice types - this is what table above references and linked answer explains as well.

Comment: You nailed it now. Non-IDR frames should have been processed as well!!