# usage of start code for H264 video

Tags: h.264

I have general question about the usage of start code (0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01) for the H264 video. I am not clear about the usage of this start code as there is no reference in the RTP RFCs that are related to H264 video. But I do see lot of reference in the net and particularly in the stackoverflow.

I am confused as I see one client doesn't have this start code and another client is using this start code. So, I am looking for a specific answer where this start code should be used and where I shouldn't.

KMurali

Comment: You will find your answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream/24890903#24890903

Comment: I am trying to stream H.264 over RTP (hence UDP) so does the start code still apply? From this [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184) it does not mention a start code and I thought the start code would not be present since UDP is packetized (not a byte stream).  Am I wrong in assuming this?  I am having problems implementing this so I thought maybe I might be wrong.

Answer (score 19):

There are two H.264 stream formats and they are sometimes called

1. Annex B (as found in raw H.264 stream)
2. AVCC (as found in containers like MP4)

An H.264 stream is made of NALs (a unit of packaging)

**(1) Annex B** : has 4-byte start code before each NAL unit's bytes `[x00][x00][x00][x01]`.

```
[start code]--[NAL]--[start code]--[NAL] etc
```

**(2) AVCC** : is size prefixed (meaning each NALU begins with byte size of this NALU)

```
[SIZE (4 bytes)]--[NAL]--[SIZE (4 bytes)]--[NAL] etc
```

Some notes :

- The AVCC (MP4) stream format doesn't contain any NALs of type SPS, PPS or AU delimter. Since that specific information is now placed within MP4 metadata.
- The Annex B format you'll find in MPEG-2 TS, RTP and some encoders default output.
- The AVCC format you'll find in MP4, FLV, MKV, AVI and such A/V container formats.

Both formats can be converted into each other.

**Annex B to MP4** : Remove start codes, insert length of NAL, filter out SPS, PPS and AU delimiter.

**MP4 to Annex B** : Remove length, insert start code, insert SPS for each I-frame, insert PPS for each frame, insert AU delimiter for each GOP.