# Decoding live H.264 stream over RTP in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, h.264, rtp, mpeg-4

**What I am trying to do**

Stream live H.264 data over the network and use hardware acceleration to decode it as specified in the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#513) so I can play it in my iOS app in real time.

**What I have tried**

I have read RFC 6184 extensively and believe I have my head wrapped around it.  I assume the RTP packets I am receiving are in the format specified in the RFC. I am also assuming the stream will be in non-interleaved mode.  So my application reads in each nalu packet and determines if it is a single nalu packet (type < 24),  aggregated packet (type = 24), or fragmented packet (type = 28).  From there I am just logging the data of what type of nalu I am receiving because I wanted to make sure the data is coming in the form I expect and being appropriately parsed before moving on.

**What happens**

When I log the nalu types I get  nal units with a type of 0, 1, 2 with occasional PPS  nalus as shown in the picture.

[image: Log of NAL unit packet types received]
 I know that I should receive a SPS and a PPS as the first 2 packets so I know something is wrong.

**My question**

I am using VLC to stream the data.  I am transcoding it in H.264 and with the encapsulation format MPEG TS.  Now, when I first started this I thought I as long as I was streaming H.264 it would be in the format specified in the RFC.  But after doing some research about MPEG TS and how it is a container format I think my stream is not in the format specified in the RFC.

If I am actually streaming the video in a format different from the RFC, how would I use VLC (or an equivalent program) to stream the data in the form of the RFC?  All the posts on SO such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream) and the WWDC video talk about looking for a start code (0x0001 or 0x000001) for each nalu but the RFC never mentions it. So I am not sure if that is the reason I am getting weird results is due to me not looking for a start code or if it is because I am not receiving the data in the RFC format. I greatly appreciate any help especially since I am new to video decoding in general and feel like I am almost there!

Comment: Have you found a solution yt?

Comment: No this project I had to reduce the scope to exclude a live video stream so unfortunately it never was implemented. Are you working on something similar to this?

Comment: Yeah...sadly not much source can be found..

Comment: I would try this book http://files.cnblogs.com/files/irish/The_H.264_advanced_video_compression_standard.pdf .  I never got the chance to read it, but it looked promising.  The other thing I was going to try which I never got the chance to was to read the source of ffmpeg or another opensource tool that can do the video streaming / compression / whatever.  I don't know for sure that it will help but searching around got me almost no where.

Comment: @JackSong any luck with that?

Comment: Hey! Thx 4 checking back, but no...we've dropped the project since..