# How to calculate MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER for MPEG4 Sink in Win7?

Tags: h.264, ms-media-foundation, mpeg-4

I have a MF topology that captures video and audio and encodes it into H264, then writes it to an MPEG4 sink. However, the problem is that my H264 encoder (Intel QuickSync H264 Encoder) does not define a value for MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER in its output types. Thus, when I set the video media type of my MPEG4 sink, no sequence header is defined and the sink cannot correctly finalize, as mentioned in the MPEG4 Sink documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763(v=vs.85).aspx

After searching around, I learned that I need to get the SPS & PPS values for the MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER attribute. I am not sure about how to get these. My application is designed only for Windows 7, but in Windows 8 it seems like you can just set the MF_MPEG4SINK_SPSPPS_PASSTHROUGH attribute to have the sink grab the SPS & PPS from the input samples (see the above link). I have no interest in individual frame samples other than to obtain this value, and currently my application code is not looking at individual H264 samples.

What is an easy way to obtain the SPS & PPS values from a MF H264 stream on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

I could explain exactly how to do it. But I believe the how will be confusing if you don't understand the why. I have another post that explains these concepts in pretty good detail, and writing the code to accomplish this should be trivial after understanding the bitstream format.

You should pay specific attention to the AVCC section

[Possible Locations for Sequence/Picture Parameter Set(s) for H.264 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream)