# Transport stream extract ES video/audio data and play it

Tags: stream, vlc, mux, mpeg-2, dvb

I am working on something and i came a point that i cannot find something useful by searching on the internet any further.

I wrote a descrambler for dvbs2 csa, now i want to try it with real data. I have a .ts file and i have the key. All i want to do is to check if my code can descramble even a single frame is sufficient for me. I can get the ES bits by following PID with a software but when i copy-paste straight forward on a file bit after bit, VLC or any other player won't play it.

What should i do?, how can i visualize ES data?

I would be appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: What codec does the ts file use?

Comment: I don't think it has any codec, it is mpeg basicly

Comment: `mpeg-ts` is a container format. The ES is the result of the encoding process. If you want to extract it you need to know what it is / what format it uses (eg: [H.264 in Annex B/AVCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that copying and pasting bits straight forward to notepad won't work. I need to write a code to write to a file those bytes. I wrote a c code for that and now it works. But i had to descramble at least 2000 packages to make it playable on a TS software.