# How can I get frame dimensions from live stream using libav C++

Tags: stream, h.264, live, dimensions, libav

I am trying to extract the frame dimensions from H.264 encoded live stream using libav and C++. I have access to the raw stream, I don't need to re-encode the frames just to parse the width and height. I think I have to get the SPS to get this information.
I found this post but it doesn't seem to help with my problem:

[How to get width and height from the H264 SPS using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787875/how-to-get-width-and-height-from-the-h264-sps-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: why does that not help? It’s a great example.

Comment: I agree it's a great example but it concerns initializing a codec context using an SPS, and I am looking to get the frame size from a raw H.264 stream, so I need to initialize my context from the raw stream parameters.

Comment: The SPS is just a packet in the raw stream. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream