# Can ffmpeg parse/decode packets in AVCC format?

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, decoder

According to [Need to convert h264 stream from annex-b format to AVCC format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404403/need-to-convert-h264-stream-from-annex-b-format-to-avcc-format):

```
AnnexB format:

([start code] NALU) | ( [start code] NALU) |

AVCC format:

([extradata]) | ([length] NALU) | ([length] NALU) |
```

Currently you can parse a bitstream (AnnexB format) using [av_parser_parse2](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/group__lavc__parsing.html#ga691ca0258e91f99297e7726f56d8c247) and then pass this buffer to `avcodec_send_frame`, but what about AVCC format? Is there a parser for it?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550420/is-the-values-in-avcc-box-in-mp4-video-files-affected-only-by-ffmpeg-version and follow the link in the answer for more info. I never heard of AVCC but it looks like it's an alternative way to store meta info other than annex B in H.264 rather than a completely different format??? And `ffmpeg` can handle it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

You will need to pass the content of the `avcC` box to [AVCodecContext::extradata](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/structAVCodecContext.html#abe964316aaaa61967b012efdcced79c4) which will be parsed by the decoder to get the PPS and SPS NALUs necessary for decoding.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```c
// `avcC` box retrieved from an MP4
char avcC[] = "...";

// Create codec parameters and copy the avcC box as extradata
codec_params = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
memcpy(codec_params.extradata, &avcC, sizeof(avcC));
codec_params.extradata_size = sizeof(avcC);

// Create the codec context and initialize it with codec parameters
codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3();
avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_context, codec_params);

// Create the codec and initialize it
codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
avcodec_open2(codec_context, codec, NULL);
```

---

The AVCC format assumes that PPS and SPS NALUs are provided "out of band", meaning they are not part of the stream like in the Annex B format. [This excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream) gives more details about the differences.

In an MP4 container, these NALUs are located in the `avcC` box, located at the following path in the MP4 box hierarchy:

```
moov > trak > mdia > minf > stbl > stsd > avc1 > avcC
```