# Missing one frame between two .ts files

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have 2 files: fileSequence0.ts and fileSequence1.ts, I use ffmpeg to inspected the number of frames of each file, the result is:

- fileSequence0.ts, 29 frames
- fileSequence1.ts, 28 frames

Then I concat the 2 files into one:

```
ffmpeg -i 'concat:fileSequence0.ts|fileSequence1.ts' -codec copy merge.mp4
```

Now, merge.mp4 has **58** frames, not **57 = 29 + 28**, what's that about, can any one point out what knowlege I am missing?

The files mentioned here can be download at: https://github.com/ideawu/missing-frame-between-ts

Answer (score 1):

The second file `fileSequence1.ts` also has **29** frames not **28**.

Because of the way it was initially segmented, if you to play it on its own you will fail to get one frame as it's missing the required SPS/PPS data:

```
[h264 @ 0x4111460] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x4111460] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x4111460] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x4111460] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x4111460] no frame!
```

Since the SPS/PPS is present in the first file and when you concat it will read `fileSequence0.ts` first it will be able to decode the lost frame, hence the result is the correct value **58**.

You can see this easily by reversing the order of the concat:

```
ffmpeg -i 'concat:fileSequence1.ts|fileSequence0.ts' -codec copy merge.mp4
```

This command results in **57** frames as it fails to decode the first one.

Comment: Many thanks! I am doing video decoding with AVAssetReader on iOS, it also tells `fileSequence1.ts` has 28 frames not 29. Now I have to learn PPS things.

Comment: @ideawu It has 29, but fails to decode one. See the Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Abstraction_Layer#Parameter_Sets) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream) on SO

Comment: Thanks again! You are such nice person!