# FFmpeg camera encode h264 mp4 muxing atom avcC is too small

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I tried to encode Android camera preview frame to h264, and mux to mp4 container.

I can created mp4 file successfully. But the mp4 format seems corrupted.

Use the `ffprobe`, I got the following error.

```
$ ffprobe o.mp4
[h264 @ 0x209fe50] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x209fe50] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x209fe50] no frame!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x209ea60] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x209ea60] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 568x320, 505 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
```

Then I use `mp4info` tool to see if the information is correct. I found this.

```
$ mp4info o.mp4 
mp4info version 2.0.0
o.mp4:
ReadProperties: atom 'avcC' is too small; overrun at property: configurationVersion (src/mp4atom.cpp,386)
mp4info: can't open o.mp4
```

By hexdump the content of file, I got this

```
$ xxd o.mp4 |grep -A 5 -B 5 avcC
0039170: 6331 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000  c1..............
0039180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0238 0140 0048  ...........8.@.H
0039190: 0000 0048 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000  ...H............
00391a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00391b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0018 ffff  ................
00391c0: 0000 0008 6176 6343 0000 0020 7374 7473  ....avcC... stts
00391d0: 0000 0000 0000 0002 0000 004f 0000 0ea6  ...........O....
00391e0: 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0058 7374 7373  ...........Xstss
00391f0: 0000 0000 0000 0012 0000 0001 0000 0005  ................
0039200: 0000 000a 0000 000f 0000 0014 0000 0019  ................
0039210: 0000 001e 0000 0023 0000 0028 0000 0029  .......#...(...)
```

If I didn't add global header to `AVCodecContext`,

```
if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
    // oc_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}
```

`ffprobe` can detect the format without error, also `ffplay` can play it. But the `avcC` atom still not correct. Other player cannot play it.

Why the muxer didn't write the correct `avcC` atom?

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You must set the extradata field in the codec context. The format is referenced here: [Possible Locations for Sequence/Picture Parameter Set(s) for H.264 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream/24890903#24890903)

Answer (score 1):

Solved. This problem only happened in the new version ffmpeg.

When call ffmpeg api `avformat_write_header/av_write_tailer`, it uses the data in `AVStream->codecpar` since `AVStream->codec` was marked deprecated.

And the extra data is filled after `avcodec_open2`, so I need to copy extra data back to `AVStream->codecpar`.

```
stream->codecpar->extradata = av_malloc(oc_ctx->extradata_size + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
stream->codecpar->extradata_size = oc_ctx->extradata_size;
memcpy(stream->codecpar->extradata, oc_ctx->extradata, oc_ctx->extradata_size);
```

Similar code snippet also can be found in ffmpeg project [ffmpeg.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffmpeg.c)

```
if (!ost->st->codecpar->extradata && avctx->extradata) {
    ost->st->codecpar->extradata = av_malloc(avctx->extradata_size + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
    if (!ost->st->codecpar->extradata) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not allocate extradata buffer to copy parser data.\n");
        exit_program(1);
    }    
    ost->st->codecpar->extradata_size = avctx->extradata_size;
    memcpy(ost->st->codecpar->extradata, avctx->extradata, avctx->extradata_size);
}
```