# How h.264 elementary stream parsing into nalu

Tags: streaming, h.264

Wondering if anyone has any insight about h.264 byte code stream:

The ffmpeg command line is:

```
 fmpeg\" -s 320x240 -f avfoundation -r 30.00 -i \"0:none\" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -x264opts crf=20:vbv-maxrate=3000:vbv-bufsize=100:intra-refresh=1:slice-max-size=1500:keyint=30:ref=1 -b:v 1000 -an -f mpegts -threads 8 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p udp://127.0.0.1:5564"
```

In theory, the elementary stream in h.264 should be like this: (**[view image](http://artsmesh.io/file/bde333e59dca5b1861afb09faa9a7b792cf38ece6676392495cd02944452bbbc.jpg)**)
[image]

So the key is to generate individual NALUs from H.264 stream. So we should get the bitstream like this: (**[view image](http://artsmesh.io/file/ce09393a8f2fb0074864aa7ae8df9e04b1c24c704859deb889e85fe3e313d573.png)**).
[image]

We need get the real NALU type like this: `0x1F` & NALU type. So `0x27` is equal to `0x67`.

Normally, we should just have these NALU type(after the operation of `0x1F` & NALU type):

1: slice of a non-IDR picture.  (P frame)

5: slice of an IDR picture.     (I frame)

6: Supplemental enhancement information. (SEI)

7: Sequence parameter set. (SPS parameter)

8: Picture parameter set. (PPS parameter)",

9: Access unit delimiter.

But what I get from udp is like this from the first  UDP packet:
[image]
<sub>(source: [artsmesh.io](http://artsmesh.io/file/92680df9bbdfdc2beb0c67b43e04f0520ef54351c709ef1fce5e5a74cff20a88.jpg))</sub>

In this UDP datagram, something doesn’t make sense, after the `0x00000001` start code header, the NALU type is `0xff`, and the second one is `0xf0`, both of them are undefined in h.264.

So I’m having trouble finding out why the h.264 stream is not working.

And is it true that the start code header is always either four bytes `0x0000 0001` or three bytes `0x000001` within the same UDP packets(or the same session of streaming)?

Comment: You miss the images I think

Comment: Thanks, but I'm the new guy here, so I can't add images, right?

Comment: Try to crop your images where you can, otherwise they are too large (height) for here. Also links to other images are missing (at least put text of links). Finally those bytes could be pasted as text (not image) then we can even test as actual bytes...

Comment: thanks a lot for your tips. VC.One

Comment: Its better to post text as text, and not an image.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a raw h.264 stream. It is a transport stream. Some of 0x000001 are from the PES header, and not part of of the AVC payload. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream

Also, 3 and 4 bytes start codes can be mixed in the same ES. The reason is covered in my answer [Possible Locations for Sequence/Picture Parameter Set(s) for H.264 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really explained a lot.