# when muxing , ffmpeg just support stereo only?

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg, stereotype

environment: ffmpeg 3.1.1, xcode 7.3.1, ios 9.3

My purpose is to mux H.264 and AAC stream(real time) to an mp4 file. Everything seems just right while recording(ffmpeg does not report an error or warning), and the result file can be played very normally on VLC. However, the file has no sound when playing on my cellphone or QuickTime on the computer, which pictures can be shown just right. I've done some analysis, and the result is:

1.video both input and output is normal and right;

2.input audio has params channel:mono & sample_rate:8000HZ, while output audio has channel:stereo & sample_rate:16000HZ(VLC told me the parameters of the output file). I didn't do any converting about the audio.

So, my question is: when muxing into mp4 file, does ffmpeg only support stereo? If not, how could I prevent this converting and make the audio played normally on cellphone and QuickTime?

Comment: What's your ffmpeg command?

Comment: I didnot use command line. The code you can see on my another question!   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012402/mux-raw-h-264-to-an-mp4-file-some-odd-errors)