# H264 Annex B NALU type

Tags: h.264, codec, libavcodec

I have Annex B formated data and I want to convert it to AvcC. As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream) to construct Avcc format you should have SPS and PPS type NALUs. But I'm receiving these bytes as Annex B formated data which doesn't have neither SPS nor PPS type NALUs. 
So I'm confused how am I going to convert these Annex B bytes to Avecc:

    Hex data: 00 00 00 01 41 9A 20 22 80 53 E1 80

So type number of this NALU is 1 and type 1 is neither SPS nor PPS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Video is unplayable until you receive and SPS, PPS and IDR (or enough I slices if the stream uses intra refresh, very unlikely). Basically that NALU is worthless. Ignore everything until you have the data you need.

I sort of cover that in the post you referenced:

> In these formats it is common to repeat the SPS and PPS periodically,
>   usually preceding every IDR thus creating a random access point for
>   the decoder. This enables the ability to join a stream already in
>   progress.

Comment: And what does it mean "bits 1-2 indicate whether a NALU is referenced by another NALU", when is NALU referenced by another NALU and how these two bits show that case?

Comment: This is a new question, and therefor should get its own post on stackoverflow.