# Why MP4 generated through FFmpeg API can't be played in the Windows Media Player?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, video-encoding

I encoded some frames into a MP4 using FFmpeg API, but the MP4 could't be played in the Windows Media Player.

By comparison with the normal MP4 using ffprobe, I found that the FOURCC of the problematic MP4 is 'H264' while the normal MP4 is 'AVC1'.
According to [H.264 Video Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757808(v=vs.85).aspx), 'AVC1' has start codes but 'H264' hasn't.I also learned that we shoud manually add sps and pps before H.264 stream when demuxing a MP4.

Now I don't know how to add start code or sps/pps to my MP4, please give me a hand.
How I should do to generate a MP4 which can be played in the Windows Media Player?

I have tried to add h264 bitstream filter but it didn't work. The code below:

```
 AVBitStreamFilterContext *bsfc = NULL;
bsfc = av_bitstream_filter_init("h264_mp4toannexb");
if (bsfc == NULL) {
            printf("bsfc is NULL\n");
}
        
av_bitstream_filter_filter(bsfc, codec_ctx, NULL, &(pkt->data), &(pkt->size), pkt->data, pkt->size, 0);

av_bitstream_filter_close(bsfc);
```

After a lot of trying, I found that  manually adding sps and pps to codec_ctx->extradata effective:

```
unsigned char sps_pps[23] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x64, 0x00, 0x29, 0xac, 0x1b, 0x1a, 0x12, 0xe0, 0x51, 0x90,
                              0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, 0xea, 0x43, 0xcb };
codec_ctx->extradata_size = 23;
codec_ctx->extradata = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(23 + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
if (codec_ctx->extradata == NULL) {
    printf("could not av_malloc the video params extradata!\n");
    ERR_NULL_EXIT
    }
memcpy(codec_ctx->extradata, sps_pps, 23);
```

The code above refered to an answer of @szatmary

Now generated MP4 can be played in Windows Media Player. But a new question emerges because I don't konw what correct value of sps/pps is. It cause that the width and height of frame presented in the Windows Explorer is incorrect. So I need to set the correct sps/pps. I also read the document of sps/pps but get confused because some parameters have variable bits. So can anybody tell me how to set the sps/pps correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the fundamental solution to the problem is that to add a line of code before the call of avcodec_open2.

```
codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
```

The encoder would set the sps/pps in the avcodec_open2() function if you set the codec_ctx->flags.

And you can refer to below sites if you want to know more about sps/pps.

[Possible Locations for Sequence/Picture Parameter Set(s) for H.264 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream)

Comment: hi James. can you share some working code snippet of this?

Comment: @Derek you can refer to FFmpeg video encode example, add this line before avcodec_open2().codec_ctx is type AVCodecContext.

Answer (score 0):

> manually adding sps and pps to codec_ctx->extradata

This works for me.

> how to set the sps/pps correctly?

I remux the video with FFmpeg command line, then use `mp4info` to read pps/sps from the remuxed video.