# Decode a single (H264) packet dumped by ffmpeg from a mp4 file

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

I used ffmpeg to dump a packet representing a single frame from an h264 video inside a mp4

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy -vframes 1 -map 0:v:0 -f data frame.bin`

The data inside `frame.bin` seems to be fine and seems to be composed of exactly the same bytes as the first chunk/packet (I'm not sure what is the correct term) from the `mdat` atom.

Now I want to decode that frame. Since I know the codec that was used to create that packet (h264), I thought I could simply prepare a codec context, load all that data into a packet and the use traditional `avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, packet)` followed by `avcodec_receive_frame()` combo.

Unfortunately the call to `avcodec_send_packet`fails and I receive the following error

`(-1094995529) Invalid data found when processing input`

Since the first 4 bytes of the packet data is the size of the packet itself, I tried skipping those bytes before passing the buffer to the packet, but that also failed.

Am I skipping some step or doing something wrong? Is what I am trying to do even possible? (please say yes :)

Comment: You’re gonna have to read up on “AVCC” vs “Annex B”.

Comment: By that you mean that simply telling ffmpeg to read back the same packet it extracted from the original file won't work?

Comment: Following your advice I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890903/1593842, which seems to be a very nice explanation and also tells me that the data ffmpeg gave me is on AVCC, but without the "header" or "extra data" or "sequence reader". So I assume that, without it, ffmpeg does not know how to interpret the data stream. Am I close?

Comment: They are the two most common ways by which H.264 NALUs can be framed, and AVCC also places SPS/PPS NALUs “out-of-line”, in FFmpeg this is called “extradata”. You’re broadly correct.

Comment: care to post this as an answer so I can accept it? You pretty much gave me all the info I needed to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ITU-T Rec. H.264 & Annex B

Recommendation H.264 is a video codec standard defined by the International Telecommunication Union, **T**elecommunications Standardization Sector (ITU-**T**). It is available **free of charge** and [can be downloaded from their website](https://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=13189).

The standard defines a bytestream format, whose lowest level of abstraction is the NALU (Network Layer Abstraction Unit).

32 types of NALUs can exist, although about 11 are reserved or unused. Some carry video slice data, some don’t. *Two NALU types will be important later in this discussion: SPS (Sequence Parameter Set) and PPS (Picture Parameter Set). Both are required to decode a video slice, and provide important information about the stream, such as its size and interpretation of the raw data.*

H.264 leaves undefined how these NALUs are transported and framed. However, it does describe one possible scheme, in the Standard’s own Annex B. This scheme, for want of a better name, is generally referred to as **Annex B**.

The scheme consists in prefixing the NALUs with an easy-to-synchronize-to start code that cannot occur within a NALU: A 3- or 4-byte pattern `00 00 01` or `00 00 00 01`. The rest of the NALU then follows. This scheme is popular in hardware and/or streaming situations because it allows acquiring bit-lock and byte-alignment easily, sends the SPS/PPS “in-band” periodically and thus allows one to tune into the stream at a random point to begin decoding, and has the interesting property that between NALUs one can validly send an arbitrary number of 0 bits or bytes.

## ISO/IEC 14496 MPEG-4 & AVCC

MPEG-4 is a family in multiple “parts” of standards for Audio-Video coding and storage made by a joint group of the International Standards Organization (ISO) and International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) called the Moving Pictures Expert Group (MPEG). A few parts only of the MPEG-4 family are relevant:

- MPEG-4 Part 10 / Advanced Video Coding (AVC), technically identical to ITU-T H.264. **Free of charge**.
- MPEG-4 Part 12, ISO Base Media File Format (BMFF), defines a generic binary container file format that can be specialized. **Free of charge**.
- MPEG-4 Part 14 (MP4), which specializes Part 12 for video in general and defines the `.mp4` file extension and format. This part is **very** expensive (**88 Swiss francs**) and not available to the public.
- MPEG-4 Part 15, which defines how NALU-structured video data such as Part 10/H.264 video is stored in the Part 12 ISO BMFF. This part is **extremely** expensive (**198 Swiss francs**), and not available to the public, but it, Part 14, 12 and 10 are the basis of the commonly-used `.mp4` container with H.264-coded video.

### AVCC

Unfortunately, Part 15 is also the part that defines a new scheme for framing of NALUs. This scheme proposes to extract all SPS/PPS NALUs into an “out-of-band” structure called **AVCC**, and also strips and replaces the start code prefixes in front of NALUs by an (almost-always) 4-byte number representing the size, in bytes, of the following NALU.

This scheme is popular for fast- and random-seeking through video data, and by gathering all video decoder configuration data (SPS/PPS) in one standardized place, one can configure the video decoder once at the beginning and thereafter not worry about unexpected surprises like a dynamic change in the size of the video frame (which Annex B allows).

Fortunately, hints about AVCC’s structure exist online, as does code to translate between AVCC and Annex B.

## Your needs

You seem to need AVCC -> Annex B conversion. This can be done with FFmpeg’s bitstream filter, [`h264_mp4toannexb`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#h264_005fmp4toannexb):

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb OUTPUT.ts
```

Comment: Thank you. During my googling I became aware of that ffmpeg filter. Although that filter is not what I need (I'm actually working with a truncated mp4 that lost the **moov** atom) , you basically taught me that, when the **SPS/PPS** data is stored somewhere else (i.e. **AVCC**) I am going to have to figure out a way to generate it and pass it to the codec. The code I was using had worked in the past, but only because I was lucky and was feeding it a stream where the configuration data came right before the video data NALU (i.e., **Annex B**).