# Why h264 over rtp doesn't contain NALU Start Codes

Tags: h.264, rtp

I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890903/12279500. , But when I looking h264 over rtp I  recognize Sps,Pps,Idr .... But didn't see h264 start code before each NALU.

Why is that?

How many h264 formats there are , not include Annex B and AVCC

Comment: Is it encoded as Annex B?

Comment: @LegendofPedro that good question, how can I recognize if it is AVCC maybe , or maybe there are another formats?

Answer (score 1):

RTP has its own payload format described
in [RFC 6184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184)

As for how many formats there are, assume infinite because nothing is stopping anybody from creating more.

Comment: thanks  , 1) Why there are infinite? If someone wants that his h264 will be played he must use one of the known formats, no?    2)Is there a simple way how to convert rtp h264 format to Annex B format?

Answer (score 0):

The start codes are used to split each NALU in byte stream because the NALU header doesn't have length info. But in rtp protocol, the NALUs are in payload field of the packet so it doesn't need the start codes. You only need to split each rtp packet.