# How to identify an IDR frame from the Video packet

Tags: mpeg2-ts

I need to be able to inspect ts packets (looking at video PID 481) and determine whether the packet contains an IDR frame. My understanding is that I need to look for a NAL unit start code, and then something else after that to signify it's the start of an IDR frame. Please can someone clarify?

Here's an example of a packet that I think is an IDR frame, but need to be able to prove it from the payload data:

```
* Packet 2
  ---- TS Header ----
  PID: 481 (0x01E1), header size: 12, sync: 0x47
  Error: 0, unit start: 1, priority: 0
  Scrambling: 0, continuity counter: 1
  Adaptation field: yes (8 bytes), payload: yes (176 bytes)
  Discontinuity: 1, random access: 1, ES priority: 0
  PCR: 0x000000013A5
  ---- PES Header ----
  Stream id: 0xE0 (Video 0)
  PES packet length: 0 (unbounded)
  ---- Full TS Packet Content ----
  47 41 E1 31 07 D0 00 00 00 08 7E E5 00 00 01 E0 00 00 84 C0 0A 31 00 05
  E5 CD 11 00 05 AD 8D 00 00 00 01 09 10 00 00 00 01 67 64 00 29 AC D9 40
  78 04 4F DE 02 94 04 04 05 00 00 03 00 01 00 00 03 00 32 E6 80 00 F4 24
  00 04 F5 8A 49 30 0F 8B 16 CB 00 00 00 01 68 FA A7 CB 00 00 01 06 00 05
  95 6C 60 E4 85 80 00 00 01 06 05 FF FF F5 DC 45 E9 BD E6 D9 48 B7 96 2C
  D8 20 D9 23 EE EF 78 32 36 34 20 2D 20 63 6F 72 65 20 31 34 38 20 2D 20
  48 2E 32 36 34 2F 4D 50 45 47 2D 34 20 41 56 43 20 63 6F 64 65 63 20 2D
  20 43 6F 70 79 72 69 67 68 74 20 32 30 30 33 2D 32 30 31 36
```

Comment: Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream ? You are lookng for IDR slice (type 5)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll have a read of this now :)

Comment: By the way, doesn't the fact that ts duck shows random access set to 1 in that packet prove that it is an IDR?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it’s likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to tell from that packet. It is however VERY likely it is an IDR. I say its likely, because looking at the NALUs, I can see an AUD `00 00 00 01 09`, an SPS `00 00 00 01 67` a PPS `00 00 00 01 68` then an SEI `00 00 01 06`

The SEI however takes the remaining bytes of the packet, You will need to continue reading packets from that PID until you fine the next NALU and see if its an IDR.