# How to use the data encoded in AVPacket to fill in RTMP_Packet and send it to RTMP server

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, packet

I am currently using ffmpeg to push live streaming, but the effect is not very good, so I want to control the details of librtmp. I know that AVPacket contains encoded data (H264 NAL, but not real NAL). I hope someone can tell me how to fill RTMP_Packet with AVPacket data. I hope there are some reference codes .Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Read this first: [Possible Locations for Sequence/Picture Parameter Set(s) for H.264 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream)

Then look at this:

https://github.com/szatmary/RtmpBroadcaster/blob/master/flvtag.cpp

And this:

https://github.com/szatmary/RtmpBroadcaster/blob/master/rtmp.cpp